# Repair Protection Covering: Rosin Paper and Masking Paper Difference

Tags: walls, repair, flooring, painting

(1) What is the difference between Rosin Paper and Masking Paper? (Besides the color). Trying to protect my home during construction.

(2) Specifically, What is better for protecting walls? I usually go with plastic, however seems the two below could be sturdier .

[image]

[Masking Paper](https://www.homedepot.com/p/TRIMACO-Easy-Mask-12-in-x-180-ft-Brown-General-Purpose-Masking-Paper-12912/202040755)

[Rosin Paper](https://www.homedepot.com/p/TRIMACO-Easy-Mask-3-ft-x-167-ft-Red-Rosin-Medium-Weight-Paper-35145/202040751)

Comment: Is the covering for the walls for dust protection, or protection from abuse? I would put this as an answer, but more answers are needed that are not particular to your question. I find that protection, when not done properly can hide damage, and will not be noticed until the protection is taken back down. Corners and door jambs are the only thing that really needs strong protection, and neither of the products you are asking about will suffice.

Comment: It would help to define "protection" .  Are you concerned about dust and /or overspray, or physical damage?

Comment: @Mattsmith5, you never did answer what you are trying to protect your walls from.  A correct answer will depend on that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rosin paper is a little thicker and heavier. It is sturdy enough to provide floor protection to some degree so it would be less likely to accidentally tear from incidental contact whereas the masking paper would be about a halfway point between printer paper and tissue paper. Masking paper is so lightweight, it is easier to tape to the wall but is mostly just to cover areas to protect from overspray while painting.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary:** Rosin Paper is for floor covering. Masking Paper is for masking off small areas.

## Rosin Paper

A light-duty floor covering (as opposed to a more costly and durable ram board type product).

The rosin paper in your link is a 3-foot x 167-foot roll; this would fit nicely in a typical hallway or stairway.

This product is used to cover large areas quickly but would not typically be used on walls.

## Masking Paper

Used to mask off horizontal or vertical surfaces to protect from overspray.

The masking paper comes in a 180-foot roll with options for different widths of 0.5, 0.75, 1, and 1.5 feet. It can be applied using a [tape and masking film dispenser](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-Hand-Masker-Painter-s-Tape-and-Masking-Film-Dispenser-1-Kit-M3000-PAK-SC/309634621) or by rolling it out and tapping separately.

Think of this product as a way of widening your masking tape. It is usually used as a precision covering and can often be combined with other products, such as used around the perimeter of a room on the floor up against the wall and then simply using drop cloths to protect the rest of the floor.

## Plastic Sheeting

Plastic sheeting is what tends to be used to cover walls. It is much more manageable to install, especially if you have it folded up so that you simply tape it at the top of the wall and unfold the plastic sheet, which is long enough to reach the floor.

Comment: can you spell out the differences? this seems to be more glossary definitions

Comment: Rosin Paper: floor covering. Masking Paper: masking off small areas.

Comment: hi @pdd please place  comment in answer, thanks ! and I can send points

Comment: Rosin papaer is an underlayment for flooring and siding. Its use as temporary construction protection in exposed applications is incidental. You'll find tons of in in surprisingly good shape on old walls when you tear the siding off, as it is essentially a paper housewrap product, before the plastics came on the market.